# RangeError: Invalid typed array length error during Deploy Azure App Service in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'm getting the following when performing Deploy Azure App Service in Azure DevOps.

```
2019-02-27T18:51:57.5018577Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy Azure App Service
2019-02-27T18:51:57.5028370Z ==============================================================================
2019-02-27T18:51:57.5028503Z Task : Azure App Service Deploy
2019-02-27T18:51:57.5029162Z Description : Update Azure App Services on Windows, Web App on Linux with built-in images or Docker containers, ASP.NET, .NET Core, PHP, Python or Node.js based Web applications, Function Apps, Mobile Apps, API applications, Web Jobs using Web Deploy / Kudu REST APIs
2019-02-27T18:51:57.5029281Z Version : 3.4.21
2019-02-27T18:51:57.5029357Z Author : Microsoft Corporation
2019-02-27T18:51:57.5029433Z Help : [More information](https://aka.ms/azurermwebdeployreadme)
2019-02-27T18:51:57.5029534Z ==============================================================================
2019-02-27T18:51:58.2314716Z Got connection details for Azure App Service:'myproject'
2019-02-27T18:52:01.5712562Z Updating App Service Application settings. Data: {"MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES":"1"}
2019-02-27T18:52:20.6292666Z Updated App Service Application settings and Kudu Application settings.
2019-02-27T18:52:20.6292953Z Rename locked files enabled for App Service.
2019-02-27T18:52:20.6811253Z ##[error]RangeError: Invalid typed array length
2019-02-27T18:52:23.2141473Z Successfully updated deployment History at https://myproject.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/31551293542097
2019-02-27T18:52:23.2230607Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure App Service
```

I don't know what script / config is controlling this and so I have no idea what array this error is referring to.

My build pipeline completed successfully.

Comment: Same problem here. In my case it's happening after updating an Angular 7 project to Angular 8. I'm using the same Release Pipeline, same repo and Build Pipelines work as expected. I tried deploying to a new AppService and same thing. Did you find any solution? Thanks

Comment: @FedericoRodriguez did any of you found a solution for it? I'm also trying to deploy an angular 8 app

Comment: @GabrielBitencourt not quite, but didn't event try to fix yet. I'll migrate again to Angular 8 next week. What I tried was deploying directly from Visual Studio a found an error in an angular/cli/bin/postinstall/script.js => SyntaxError: Unexpected token (. I guess it could be something regarding the CLI version.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the cool thing is that the Azure App Deploy script is [open source](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/2fc8f681a6ac614fbb500f79a70a577c5ad9639a/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4). I'm not exactly sure where the Range Error is bubbling up from; but if I had to guess, I would say it's occurring when the script is doing some file IO operation per your deployment options (image below).

One thing to look at are the files on your web app and see if anything looks suspicious like an old file that hadn't been updated in while. Since your deployment succeeds and your app runs fine, it could be something content related.

[image: Azure App Deployment Options]